# How to solve NullPointerExpression in Android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, manifest

I have a problem while using a database. When I run my SQLView.java, I get a fatal exception. I'll post all my database-related code.

See my commenting lines on Database class (line 71), and SQLView class (Line 14). Maybe there is something wrong? I've tried many things like put in: this, of null.

Also, I've read all related nullpointerexception-question on this website.

To begin: my Database class:

```
    package com.jacob.eindproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

import java.sql.*;

public class Database {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "persons_hotness";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Databasedb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"                    
        );


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void close(Database database) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }



    public Database(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;        
    }

    public void close() {

    ourHelper.close(); //This is line 71, where also an error is given, maybe there should me text between the brackets ()?
}



    public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(DATABASE_NAME);
        int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + "\n";


        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The SQLite class, to fix the input:

```
package com.jacob.eindproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class SQLite extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button sqlUpdate, sqlView;
    EditText sqlName, sqlHotness;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqllite);
        sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLUpdate);
        sqlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLName);
        sqlHotness = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLHotness);

        sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLopenView);
        sqlView.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
        sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.bSQLUpdate:


            boolean didItWork = true;
            try{            
            String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
            String hotness = sqlHotness.getText().toString();

            Database entry = new Database(SQLite.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name, hotness);
            entry.close();

            }catch (Exception e ){
                didItWork = false;

            }finally{
                if (didItWork){
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Heak Yeay");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Succes");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
            }
        }

            break;
        case R.id.bSQLopenView:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.jacob.eindproject.SQLVIEW");
            startActivity(i);


        }
        }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

After that, my SQLView class, to view the input from the SQLite class:

```
package com.jacob.eindproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SQLView extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
        Database info = new Database(this); //as you can see in the logcat, this is line 14, where the error is. Maybe the "this" isn't right?

        info.open();
        String data = info.getData();
        info.close();
        tv.setText(data);





    }

}
```

Now, my xml files, maybe I haven't configured a button not well, or something?

SQLView.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">

        <TableRow>

                <TextView android:text="@string/Names" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView android:text="@string/Hotness" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvSQLinfo" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/info"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The sqllite.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Naam" 
        android:text="@string/Naam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSQLName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hotness" 
        android:text="@string/hotnessscale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    /> 

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSQLHotness"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSQLUpdate"
        android:text="@string/Update"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSQLopenView"
        android:text="@string/View"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    ></Button>    

</LinearLayout>
```

The Menu class, to fix the menu, with an OnListItemClick (there are some other activities in there, such as Overgewicht. Don't mind these, I guess..?):

```
package com.jacob.eindproject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener { 


    String classes[] = { "BMI- Calculator", "Ondergewicht", "Gezond Gewicht", "Overgewicht", "Database", "Bekijk Database"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Positie 0 is het eerste item (dus de BMI-Calculator.)
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    switch(position)
    {
    case 0: 
    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(openStartingPoint);   
    break;

    case 1: 
    Intent openOndergewicht = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ondergewicht.class);
    startActivity(openOndergewicht);
    break;

    case 2: 
    Intent openGezondgewicht = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Gezond_gewicht.class);
    startActivity(openGezondgewicht);   
    break;

    case 3: 
    Intent openOvergewicht = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Overgewicht.class);
    startActivity(openOvergewicht); 

    break;


    case 4: 
    Intent openDatabase = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SQLite.class);
    startActivity(openDatabase);    

    break;

    case 5: 
    Intent openViewdatabase = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SQLView.class);
    startActivity(openViewdatabase);    

    break;

    }


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

My Android Manifest file: (again, I've declared some other things, don't mind these!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jacob.eindproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Inleiding"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                     <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </activity>        

        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Ondergewicht"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>        

        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Gezond_gewicht"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>   

        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Overgewicht"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Database"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.DATABASE" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </activity>                 

        <activity
            android:name=".SQLView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.SQLVIEW" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>                     

        </activity>           


        <activity
            android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.SQLite"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.SQLITE" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </activity>  



    </application>

</manifest>
```

At last, my LogCat, to show you the error:

```
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jacob.eindproject/com.jacob.eindproject.SQLView}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.jacob.eindproject.Database.getData(Database.java:95)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at com.jacob.eindproject.SQLView.onCreate(SQLView.java:16)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-14 11:04:18.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT:

I have a new error now, please take a look at my LogCat. I think it's because I have a wrong column set or something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try to change `Intent i = new Intent("com.jacob.eindproject.SQLVIEW");` to `Intent i = new Intent(this, SQLView.class);`? in `SQLite class` (R.id.bSQLopenView).. i just have a thing in my mind.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it, but it didn't really matter! Still thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE occurs at line 71 of your `Database` class, somewhere within the constructor or when intializing variables (that's what `<init>` in the stacktrace stands for.
I just read that you figured that out yourself. So the only thing that can be null here is `ourHelper`.

Is this really your code?

```
public void close() {
    } {
    ourHelper.close(); //This is line 71, where also an error is given, maybe there should me text between the brackets ()?
}
```

There's something wrong with the brackets here. I'm not sure why this compiles but I guess it does and the compiler executes the

```
{
    ourHelper.close();
}
```

immediately when instantiating the class.

Change this to

```
public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: +1 - FYI That mistake he made (the brackets) is creating what's called an instance initiator which is why it compiles. That block of code runs prior to the constructor.

Comment: @BrianRoach Yes I thought so (I only know that with `static {}`) but I'm sure that's not what the SO intended to do here.

Comment: Agreed - was just clarifying what it was and why it compiled. Changed wording in comment; it's technically not a syntax error since it's valid syntax :)

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! It does work now! Thank you @BrianRoach aswell! All the best, Jacob

Comment: @BrianRoach. Hello Brian, thank you for your reply. I have another question. When I run my project and fill in the 'Name' and 'Hotness', I get an fatal exception. I've edited the LogCat, can you please take a look? Thank you in advance!! Jacob